# How can I change SQL Server Management Studio Results

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to change the results of a TSQL statement to an edit grid without having to right click on the table name in object explorer and choosing the "Edit  Rows" option?  Is there any way I can script it so I don't have to select the edit option everytime.

Thanks in advance,

.EGB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this isn't possible.

The "Results to Grid" option is a read only results grid.

Once you are in Edit table mode you can click "show sql pane" and enter arbitrary queries unrelated to the original table though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can edit the grid that gives the result because if you edit the values they might no longer qualify in the result set. You can always use Update queries :p

You can use query designer but I don't think that's what you're looking for.